Bounding a certain function
I'm currently watching a lecture where we have a function that looks like
$$C_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_{k=1}^{q^2 -1} \lambda_{k}^{t} {\rm tr}(o_{\alpha} u_k) {\rm tr}(o_{\beta} v_k).$$
Now, ${\rm tr}(o_{\alpha} u_k)$ and ${\rm tr}(o_{\beta} v_k)$ are just some scalars which depend on the specific observables inside the trace but the important part here are the values $\lambda_k$ which are eigenvalues of some unistochastic map, meaning that the set $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^{q^2 -1}$ lies on the unit disk and some on the unit circle.
The lecturer then goes on and discusses the specific case where we have for all eigenvalues $$\mid \lambda_k \mid < 1 ,$$
i.e. they all lie on the unit disk. Because of that, you can draw a circle around all of these eigenvalues and the radius of this circle will always be less than $1$. He denotes the difference between the radius of this smaller circle and the unit circle $\Delta$.
He then says that that it's very easy to show that in the long time limit $t \to \infty$ the function above will exponentially decay and be bounded by $$C_{\alpha\beta} \leq K e^{-\Delta t},$$
whre $K$ is some constant.
The problem I'm having is that I'm not really seeing how one can come up with this.  My guess is that it has something to do with taking the largest eigenvalue $1 - \Delta$ and then bounding
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}C_{\alpha\beta}\leq K\lim_{t\to\infty}(1-\Delta)^{2t}$$ but for that to work I would need to somehow get $t$ into the denominator.
Another approach I thought about is to write
$$C_{\alpha\beta}\leq Ke^{t\log(1-\Delta)}$$
and then Taylor expand the logarithm. However, I guess this would work only for small gaps $\Delta$?
If anyone's interested to help out I would highly appreciate it. The lecture in question can be found here: https://youtu.be/4iNPVf4piWo?si=MVvf2-bce-657LzD
He talks about it around the 1:00:40 mark.

Hi,  so in $C_{\alpha\beta}$ the value $\lambda_k$ is raised to the power of $t$. Do you mean this dependence?

Sorry. I missed that. Maybe my brain was just interpreting it as a "transpose" symbol (yes - obviously not, but when you first read it, it isn't obvious what sort of objects the various symbols represent). My apologies.

$\log(1-\Delta) + \Delta$ has its maximum at $\Delta = 0$ where it is $0$. Thus $\log(1-\Delta) < -\Delta$ and $e^{t\log(1-\Delta)} < e^{-t\Delta}$ for $t > 0$.

Oh, I see, it's that easy actually... One just bounds the function again. I did not think of that. Thank you!
